# How do I align 3 circular images?

Tags: html, css, image, geometry, centralized

So I have this code:

```css
/*--- Circular images --- */
.img-circular1, .img-circular2, .img-circular3{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 float: left;
 background: red;
}
.img-circular1{
   background-image: url('/Images/learn.jpg');
}
.img-circular2{
   background-image: url('/Images/watch.jpg');
}
.img-circular3{
   background-image: url('/Images/practice.jpg');
}
#container1
{
top: 100px; 
    position: relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:70%;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" style="padding-bottom: 500px;">
<div class="img-circular1"></div>
<div class="img-circular2"></div>
<div class="img-circular3"></div>
<div class="img-circular1"></div>
</div>
```

I have no managed to get 2 of them to show in a green box. But the third (which I duplicated before and after the other 2) will not show for some reason?

Also, they are not equidistant apart - how can I get them an equal spacing apart?

Please help

**NOTE**: Instead of images there are red circles, just for visibility reasons.

Comment: Also, totally irrelevant to the question, but an important thing to keep in mind is that in CSS, all prefixed properties should be *before* the un-prefixed property (in this case the webkit and moz prefixes of `border-radius` should come before).

Comment: Thanks - I have switched them around but still getting a couple of errors - have updated question with new code + errors

Answer (score 1):

Apply `float: left` on images themself, not on container:

```css
/*--- Circular images --- */
.img-circular1, .img-circular2, .img-circular3{
 /*width: 200px;*/
 /*height: 200px;*/
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
  border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 float: left;
}
.img-circular1{
   background-image: url('/Imageslearn.jpg');
   background: #aaa; /*added to as an alternative to image*/
}
.img-circular2{
   background-image: url('/Images/watch.jpg');
   background: #aaa; /*added to as an alternative to image*/
}
.img-circular3{
   background-image: url('/Images/practice.jpg');
      background: #aaa; /*added to as an alternative to image*/
}
.container1{
 left: 15%; 
 width: 70%; 
/*  float: left;  */
 height: 300px;
 position: relative; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="container1">
<div class="img-circular1"></div>
<div class="img-circular2"></div>
<div class="img-circular3"></div>
</div>
```

To answer your second question:

1. wrap circles in some other div
2. make their width be some percentage value and float them left
3. set margin on circles to `margin: 0 auto`.

Here is prototype for you to study:

```css
#green {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box; /*good for when there is border or padding*/
}

#red {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="green">
  <div id="blue">
    <div id="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="blue">
    <div id="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="blue">
    <div id="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="blue">
    <div id="red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated question with my current code and problem - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code to use [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Since you want your circles to be equally spaced across the row, `float: left` won't help much. I had to add a wrapper div around each circle div so that it could expand to fill the space without distorting the circles.

```css
/*--- Circular images --- */

.img-circular1,
.img-circular2,
.img-circular3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-circular1 {
  background-image: url('/Images/learn.jpg');
}

.img-circular2 {
  background-image: url('/Images/watch.jpg');
}

.img-circular3 {
  background-image: url('/Images/practice.jpg');
}

#container1 {
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1" style="padding-bottom: 500px;">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```